# ¿Cómo evitar que ventana WPF cubra toda la pantalla?

Tags: wpf

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en WPF y me ha surgido un pequeño problema, cuando maximizo la ventana me cubre toda la pantalla, pero quiero que no se oculte la barra de tareas, en WindowsForms lo hacia con la ayuda de la clase Screen, pero al parecer en WPF esta clase no la puedo usar, alguien que me oriente con esto.

Comment: al maximizar no deberia cubrirte la barra de tareas, salvo que el windows donde estes trabajando te permita hacerlo. Como es que la maximizas?? te pasa con otros programas?

Comment: lo que pasa es que estoy haciendo un formulario personalizado, como comento, cuando uso windowsform uso la clase Screen para obtener las dimensiones del escritorio, pero con WPF esa parte cambia, y no me deja usar esa clase

Comment: En WPF tienes la clase System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth y System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight para obtener las dimensiones de la pantalla.